# Composing a function with its antiderivative

Tags: calculus

What does it mean that, given a function and its antiderivative, if I make the composition $ g(h(x))=h(g(x)) =   \alpha(x) $? I mean, I was thinking that $ \alpha(x) $ could be some sort of identity function.

For example: 
Given, 
$g(x) =\dfrac {x^3}{3}$, 
$h(x) =x^2$, then  $ g(h(x))=\dfrac {x^6}{3}= h(g(x))$ where $\dfrac {x^6}{3}=\alpha(x) $

Comment: Just composition of functions...Did you expect something special?

Comment: well, it is not true that g(h(x))always equals h(g(x)). Besides I'm studyng the fundamental theorem of Calculus and this question dropped by.

Comment: Yes, of course it is not true in general, and it is neither in your example as $$h(g(x))=h\left(\frac{x^3}3\right)=\frac{x^6}9\;\ldots$$ I also can't see the relation of this with the FTC, though it sure can serve somehow to use the chain rule.

Comment: you're mean! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your functions $g(x)$, and $h(x)$, $g(h(x)) = g(x^2) = \dfrac{(x^2)^3}{3} = \dfrac{x^6}{3}$, and $h(g(x)) = h\left(\dfrac{x^3}{3}\right) = \left(\dfrac{x^3}{3}\right)^2 = \dfrac{x^6}{9} \neq g(h(x))$. This means in general it does not hold that the composition of a function and its own anti-derivative commutes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "the" antiderivative $F(x)$ is going to give you the area under the curve $f$ from $-\infty$ to $x$.  So if you compose that with the function $f$, you're going to get the area under the curve of $f$ from $-\infty$ to $f(x)$.

Just for the fun of it, try to compute the derivative of $F(f(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

since

$h(x)=x^2$ and $ g(x)=\dfrac{x^3}3$

then

$h(g(x))= (\dfrac{x^3}3)^2$  equals $ \dfrac{x^6}9$, **not** $ \dfrac{x^6}3$

That identity you have there is untrue, but what you may be thinking of is the chain rule which states:

$ d/dx (h(g(x)) = g'(x) * h'(g(x))$

I hope this helps you understand